# Total number of records in a bulk of data based on attr. categories

Tags: python, database, reinforcement-learning

I have data that contains 5 attributes `x1, x2, x3, x4, x5`. `x1` with binary cases, let us say `(0 s,1 s)`. `x2` are `(0 s, 1 s, and 2 s)`, `x3` are five-folds  `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and so on.

How to calculate the total number of cases?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a simple real-life sample?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Markus

I tried to apply set theory and I found that cartesian product can solve what I am intending to do.

The variables are my sets. I took the number of the unique values in each set and multiplied them. The result is correct.

The following link may be helpful:

https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/injective-surjective-bijective.html